# How to display data from database in excel form in android

Tags: android, excel, gridview

How do i display data and display such that it looks like excel sheet and upon selecting a row it should open another activity that contains selected row data in editable mode.
i know how to use list view but unable to figure out how to show data like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use gridView to create a fourm like excel sheet.
try [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

use simple tableLayouts and set onClickListener on each field inside of it